# Routers cascade - PING packet lost and no connection

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I am currently living in an apartment with a shared WiFi that works as in most hotels: the network is open and a password is required using a login page in the browser. However, a separated LAN is provided were no login is needed, so I decided to create my internal network using an ASUS AC68U because I would like to connect different devices among which a Google Home.

The network topology is as follow:

- 192.168.11.1 is the default gateway for the shared WiFi connection
- 192.168.10.1 is the default gateway for the LAN connection
- 192.168.1.1 is the default gateway that I setup for my ASUS router.

Connecting my MacBook Pro 2015 to the LAN works as expected: the computer takes the IP using DHCP and I can navigate. I can also try to setup the IP statically assigning:

- gateway: 192.168.10.1
- mask: 255.255.255.0
- ip: 192.168.10.101

Also with static IP it works without any issue.

Now I tried to connect the ASUS router to the same exact LAN to create my internal network. At first it worked, after a week or so it disconnected (the shared WiFi connection was working) but after 10-12 hours it came back. After another week (3 days ago) it failed again, so I waited 24h and still it was not working. On the ASUS webpage the router was switching between "The DHCP of your ISP is not working properly", "Disconnected", "Connected with IP 192.168.10.102".

I tried:

- a reboot
- a factory reset
- setup the IP statically from the ASUS router in case that DHCP was the problem.
- I connected the "shared" LAN to the PC and the network was working normally, so it is not a problem of the router of the building.
- to use LAN4 port in place of the WAN in case it was a faulty port
- to install the latest official update and the latest update of the Merlin software

Nothing was working, the router was still cycling between the same 3 messages.

So, I decided to go deeper. In connected the PC to the "shared" LAN and I started to `ping` the gateway at 192.168.10.1:

- packet loss: 0%
- avg time: 3ms

I reconnected the ASUS router to the "shared" LAN and the PC to the ASUS router using the LAN. `ping 192.168.1.1` (the ASUS router) gave me:

- packet loss: 0%
- avg time: 0.4ms

However, ping the "shared"router passing through the ASUS router (`ping 192.168.10.1`):

- packet loss: 40%
- avg time: 3ms

Ok, so now I know where the problem is, but I can't understand why there is that problem. From the tests I know that the LAN network card of the ASUS works, DHCP works, the LAN cables work, the "shared" router works (at least on my PC). I have no more ideas at this point.

To be clear, I cannot access the router of the building anyhow: it is a pfSense installation accessible only by LAN connection, protected by password, so no luck.

Comment: Did your ASUS router really get a DHCP lease of 192.168.1.102 on its WAN port, or was that a typo and you meant to write 192.168.10.102? If it really was a 1 in that third octet, someone probably accidentally put a rogue DHCP server on the building's LAN. So your traffic through your ASUS router may be going through a neighbor's misconfigured router before getting to the building's official router.